# SQL Server Database errors 8935/8934/8977

Tags: sql-server

I received a database from a customer, that i have to try to recover.
I'm facing some problems, specifically with the following errors:

```
(Error, Level, State, MessageText, RepairLevel, Status, DbId, DbFragId, ObjectId, IndexId, PartitionId, AllocUnitId, RidDbId, RidPruId, File, Page, Slot, RefDbId, RefPruId, RefFile, RefPage, RefSlot, Allocation) VALUES
(8935, 16, 1, N'Table error: Object ID 41, index ID 1, partition ID 281474979397632, alloc unit ID 281474979397632 (type In-row data). The previous link (1:9273) on page (1:5860) does not match the previous page (1:14296) that the parent (1:7132), slot 170 expects for this page.', N'repair_rebuild', 0, 30, 1, 41, 1, 281474979397632, 281474979397632, 30, 0, 1, 5860, 0, 30, 0, 1, 7132, 170, 1), 
(8977, 16, 1, N'Table error: Object ID 41, index ID 1, partition ID 281474979397632, alloc unit ID 281474979397632 (type In-row data). Parent node for page (1:9273) was not encountered.', N'repair_rebuild', 0, 30, 1, 41, 1, 281474979397632, 281474979397632, 30, 0, 1, 9273, 0, 30, 0, 1, 9274, 0, 1), 
(8977, 16, 1, N'Table error: Object ID 41, index ID 1, partition ID 281474979397632, alloc unit ID 281474979397632 (type In-row data). Parent node for page (1:9274) was not encountered.', N'repair_rebuild', 0, 30, 1, 41, 1, 281474979397632, 281474979397632, 30, 0, 1, 9274, 0, 30, 0, 1, 14296, 0, 1), 
(8934, 16, 1, N'Table error: Object ID 41, index ID 1, partition ID 281474979397632, alloc unit ID 281474979397632 (type In-row data). The high key value on page (1:14296) (level 0) is not less than the low key value in the parent (0:1), slot 0 of the next page (1:9274).', N'repair_rebuild', 0, 30, 1, 41, 1, 281474979397632, 281474979397632, 30, 0, 1, 14296, 0, 30, 0, 1, 9274, 0, 1)
```

I already used a lot of configurations of DBCC commands but without success.

```
ALTER DATABASE [PRI0492004] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DBCC CHECKDB ([PRI0492004], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [PRI0492004] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [PRI0492004] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DBCC Checkdb([PRI0492004], REPAIR_rebuild)
go
ALTER DATABASE [PRI0492004] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

Any comment about what i can do to get free of these errors?

Comment: Could you add some extra information about which DBCC commands you've used?

Comment: Is this the only recent backup they have? What version did the backup come from? What version was it originally on? Object_id 41 is `syscolpars` - I suspect that for this to be corrupt either the backup is from SQL Server 2000, or came from there at some point, back when you could modify system catalogs.

Comment: This isfrom the original MDF as the last backup was made about a month ago. It's from SQL 2008 r2.

Comment: Do you know if the last backup can run a clean checkdb?  What was the output of the REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS command?  And is all the user data accessible?  If it is you can create a new database and move it over.